# SVG Cut off in phone view

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, svg

I'm having issue where the site logo gets cut off in phone but not in desktop. I've tried different things such as using `<img/> <a> <div>` but same issue.

Here's how it looks in phone: http://saarman.net/storage/123-mob.jpg

Here's how it looks in desktop: http://saarman.net/storage/123-web.jpg

Also notice in mobile the text is less bold than it is in browser. What could be the issue?

Here's the CSS I use inside the `<a>` where the logo is:

```
display: block;
width: 300px;
height: 80px;
background-image: url("../image/logo-dark.svg");
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-indent: -99999em;'
```

Tested with android phone using chrome browser

Comment: do you have a `viewBox` in the svg file? Maybe limiting the viewBox to the limits of the image...

Comment: Maybe you can find your answere here : https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

Comment: You are going to need to show us the SVG.  The contents of the SVG are a factor here.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that your DIV is getting out of the screen.
Probably this would work for you:

```
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
```

**Note:** You also might need to play with the height. However the following should do the work

```
    height: auto;
```

Comment: The issue doesn't seem to be that the div cuts it off, it's that the SVG literally just ends... Here's how it looks with background-size: 40% 40% and repeat-x: http://saarman.net/storage/123-mob2.jpg

Comment: Also something odd. If I set the width to 200% and using the same background-size: 40% 40%, then the full svg appears... I'm so confused http://saarman.net/storage/123-mob3.jpg

Comment: Yep, my false. You said that you've tried with <img/> tag but with no success. 
Did you try this:
<img src="../image/logo-dark.svg" class="my-logo" />

CSS:
.my-logo {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}